# Checking injectivity of linear operator under assumptions on the adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

**Motivation (skip if you want)**. I am reading a classic paper by Donaldson about orientation of Yang-Mills moduli space https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214441485
I am having an hard time in understanding the proof of Lemma 3.9
I'll abstract the setup for you.

**Setup**. Let $A:X\to Y$ be a bounded Fredholm operator between Hilbert spaces. Suppose that 
$$||A^*y||\geq \frac 1 2 ||y||$$
(A is the operator $\hat{D}_u\oplus \hat{S}$ in Donaldson's paper) so that 
*$A$ is surjective*.
Let $V<X$ be a subspace such that
$$||A v||<\frac 1 2  ||v||\quad \quad \forall v\in V$$

> This should imply that the projection onto the kernel of $A$, $\pi:X\to \ker A$ is injective when restricted to $V$.
>   How can we prove that  $\pi|_V$ is injective? Or equivalently 
>   $$V\cap \ker A^\perp = V\cap Im(A^*)=\emptyset.$$

Comment: It should be $||Av|| < \frac{1}{2}||v||$ for $v \in V\setminus\{0\}$, and the conclusion should be $V \cap \ker A^\perp = V \cap Im(A^*) = \{0\}$. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $v \in V\setminus\{0\}$ has $v = A^*y$. Then, since $||v|| \ge \frac{1}{2}||y||$ and $||Av|| < \frac{1}{2}||v||$, $$||v||^2 = \langle A^*y, v\rangle = \langle y, Av\rangle \le ||y|| \text{ } ||Av|| < 2||v|| \frac{1}{2}||v||,$$ a contradiction.